# retrieving data through rest web services

Tags: sockets, rest, jakarta-ee

I am sending some data to the IP over my server by a GPRS module as packet data.I need to capture them in rest web service.My doubt is that can I directly access that data through a `@GET` annotation?

I mean:

```
@GET
@Path("/hello/username")
public String hello(@PathParam("username") String val) {
.....
.....
.
}
```

So i mean from the above code can I retrieve the packet data from server to the String val?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you should put the path parameter inside braces, i.e.

```
@GET
@Path("/hello/{username}")
public String hello(@PathParam("username") String val) {
```

Comment: thanks remigio. so accordingly i would be getting exact packet data over variable 'val' right?

Comment: Yes, path parameters behave exactly as normal ones